# Are lists mutable?

Tags: python, list, mutable

It is said Lists in python are mutable.
When I write code like below,

```
l1=[6,7,8,4,3,10,22,4]
l2=l1
l1.append(30)
print(l1)
print(l2)
```

both l1 and l2 prints the same list: `[6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 10, 22, 4, 30]`

But when i give code like below,

```
l1=[6,7,8,4,3,10,22,4]
l2=l1
l1=l1+[30]
print(l1)
print(l2)
```

`l1` prints --> `[6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 10, 22, 4, 30]`
`l2` prints --> `[6, 7, 8, 4, 3, 10, 22, 4]`

So, now there references have changed. So are lists in python really mutable?

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator is not a mutator, it returns a new list containing the concatenation of the input lists.

On the other hand, the `+=` operator is a mutator. So if you do:

```
l1 += [30]
```

you will see that both `l1` and `l2` refer to the updated list.

This is one the subtle differences between `x = x + y` and `x += y` in Python.

Comment: I have similar question regarding python tuples. It says" A tuple can not be changed in any way once it is created.".But when i do following t1=(4,5,8,2,3)
t1=t1+(7,1)
print(t1)
the tuple is changing as (4, 5, 8, 2, 3, 7, 1). why is that? what is really mean by tuple is immutable?

Answer (score 3):

Lists in Python are mutable. The reason for the references' change is that the `+` operator does create a new list with values of it's operands. On the other hand, the `+=` operator does the addition in-place:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3]
>>> l2 = l1
>>> l1 += [30]
>>> l2
[1,2,3,30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `l1+[30]` creates a new list that is a concatenation of both lists. That's how `+` works on lists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are mutable.

In your second example you are overwriting the value of `l1` with a new list, rather than modifying the object it refers to.

To modify the original list, you could use the `+=` operator:

```
l1 += [30]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable in python, but adding two lists will create a new object. You can verify if two objects are the same by checking their `id`. For instance:

```
In [1]: list1 = [1, 2]
In [2]: list2 = [3]

In [3]: id(list1)
Out[3]: 4359455952

In [4]: id(list2)
Out[4]: 4358798728

# Creates a new list
In [5]: list1 = list1 + [42]

In [6]: list1
Out[6]: [1, 2, 42]

# The id of the list1 is different
In [7]: id(list1)
Out[7]: 4359456024

# Mutate the list1 by appending an integer
In [8]: list1.append(53)

# The object is the same.
In [9]: id(list1)
Out[9]: 4359456024
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

When you declare L2 you are declaring a reference to an object (the list) and when you redeclare L1 you are creating a new list and changing what L1 references.  So in the end L2 references what started as L1 and L1 now references a new object.